# Cascading drop-down lists in C# MVC using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on Cascading dropdown lists in C# MVC using jquery, I'm populating the drop=downs from Database. But the drop-down doesn't populate according to the selection in the previous drop. Could you please tell what is it that I'm doing wrong? I think the `public JsonResult GetLengthList(int MaterialId)` is not being hit at all.

Length is a drop-down dependent on Material drop-down

below is my code.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetLengthList(int MaterialId)
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    List<Length> LengthList = db.Lengths.Where(x => x.MaterialId == MaterialId).ToList<Length>();
    //List<Length> LengthList = db.Lengths.ToList();
    return Json(LengthList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-5">

                @if (ViewBag.MaterialList != null)
                {

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId,
                     ViewBag.MaterialList as SelectList,
                     "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length.LengthId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Length.LengthId,
                        new SelectList(" "),
                        "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length.LengthId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript in View**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MaterialId").change(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("GetLengthList", "Drawing")', { MaterialId: $("#MaterialId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#LengthId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#LengthId").append("<option value='" + row.LengthId + "'>" + row.LengthValue + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you think your method isn't getting hit, why not add a breakpoint or logging to verify? Questioning your assumptions when debugging is great, but make sure you follow up by actually seeking answers. Verify your server side gets hit, examine the network call, add breakpoints and console.log statements in your JavaScript, examine the HTML. Find where things stop fitting your assumptions and then back track until you find the root cause.

Comment: Your dropdwonlist generates `Material_MaterialId`. You can specify a custom id here: `htmlAttributes: new { id="MaterialId", @class = "control-label col-md-2" }`. Same goes for the second dropdown.

Comment: @mason, Thanks for your suggestion, will keep that in mind and follow. I did add a breakpoint to verify, I'm very new to C# and Web development, so  was not very sure.

Comment: @adiga, Thank you! Now I understand what was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an `<select>` element with `id="MaterialId"`. Your `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId, ...)` line of code generates a `<select>` with `id="Material_MaterialId"`

Nor do you have an element with `id="LengthId"` - its `id="Length_LengthId"`

Change you script to

```
var lengthSelect = $('#Length_LengthId');
$("#Material_MaterialId").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetLengthList", "Drawing")', { MaterialId: id }, function (data) {
        lengthSelect.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, row) {
            lengthSelect.append("<option value='" + row.LengthId + "'>" + row.LengthValue + "</option>")
        });
    });
})
```

I also suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym), in particular the controller code to know how to implement this correctly so that it can be used for editing existing items, and allow you to return the view if `ModelState` is invalid without losing the data the user entered, and to return only the data you need to generate the `<option>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and answer! It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $("select#ClassId").change(function (evt){
            if ($("select#ClassId").val() != "-1"){
                $('#StudentId').empty();
                $('#StudentId').append("<option value='0'>Select Student</option>");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/JSonDropDownlist/GetStudentbyClassID",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { ClassId: $("select#ClassId").val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $.each(result, function (i, result) {
                            $('#StudentId').append("<option value=" + result.Value + ">" + result.Text + "</option>");
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) { alert("Something seems Wrong");}
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```